# can not call array values from php ini file using parse_ini_file

Tags: php

I have tried reading parameters from php ini files using **parse_ini_file**

Here is my code

```
$param_array=parse_ini_file("test.ini");
print $param_array[0];
print $param_array[1];
```

Above code returns nothing

test.ini file contains,

```
[names]
me = Robert
you = Peter

[urls]
first = "http://www.example.com"
second = "http://www.w3schools.com"
```

Now i need to call the Robert & Peter

Comment: It should be `$param_array["me"]` instead of `$param_array[0]`. I can only second @popnoodles, use [PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) instead, it's reliable and there is plenty of examples too.

Comment: Do this `if (!$param_array=parse_ini_file("test.ini")) echo 'nope';` and `print_r($param_array);` and show us what you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd have rather consulted the [Manual Pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) instead of [w3fools](http://w3fools.com), you'd have seen a reliable example where it's shown that the returned array is associative, that is, the names of the properties are the keys of the array.
So instead of

```
$param_array[0]
```

you should use

```
$param_array['me']
```

to access "Robert"

Answer (score 1):

`parse_ini_file` returns an associative array. You are trying to access the fields in your array using numerical indices, but they aren't defined.

Try accessing those fields using the names you gave them in the ini-file as the key:

```
echo $param_array['me']; // will yield Robert
```

Helpful tip: investigate the structure of arrays and variables to find out what they look like using `print_r` or `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked!

```
print $param_array["me"];
print $param_array["you"];
```